# how do I determine what items are included pending check-ins programatically?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I can query PendingSets and candidate PendingSets, and there appears to be no way to tell between included pending changes, and excluded pending changes.

I have one file included in the included changes to check in via Visual Studio Team Explorer.

Using Tfs dlls to query  I get that there are 112 pending, and 145 CandidatePending:

```
var tfsServer = Macros.TfsModule.GetTfsServerFromEnvironment();

var tfs =new Macros.TFS(tfsServer,"Development", null);
var vcs= tfs.Tfs.GetService<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer>();
var searchBase=vcs.GetItem("$/");
//vcs.Dump();
var workspace = vcs.GetWorkspace(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%devroot%"));

// vcs.QueryWorkspaces(null,null,null).Dump("workspaces");
var itemSpecs = new []{new ItemSpec(searchBase.ServerItem,RecursionType.Full)};

vcs.QueryPendingSets(itemSpecs, workspace.Name, workspace.OwnerName, false, true)
    .Select(ps=>new {Pending=ps.PendingChanges.Select(pc=>new{ pc.LocalOrServerItem,PendingChange=Util.OnDemand("PendingChange",()=> pc)}), ps.CandidatePendingChanges})
    .First()
    .Dump();

workspace.Dump();
```

The 112 value does line up with included+excluded. The 465 value lines up with the Detected add(s) value.

However I've been completely unable to figure out which changes are currently included. I've tried Tfs dll querying, and `EnvDte` for hours.

Can I programatically get the list of included changes currently (and even better, change the include/exclude list) ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the functionality you are requesting (getting/modifying the set included and excluded changes) is part of the "Pending Changes" window itself, not part of the TFS API. See [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a4066695-dfec-48cf-8743-eef6088923cf/programmatically-open-pending-changes-window-and-add-work-item?forum=vsx) for an example of how to interact with the "Pending Changes" window (partially via reflection). Maybe that is a considerable starting point for further exploration.

**EDIT**

I just explored this further and came up with the following code. It primarily utilizes the interface *Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.PendingChanges.IPendingChangesDataProvider*, which is internal to the assembly *Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.dll*.

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace PrettyFlyForANamespace
{
    public class PendingChangesInclusion
    {
        private readonly Action<IList<PendingChange>> _includeChanges;
        private readonly Action<IList<PendingChange>> _excludeChanges;
        private readonly Func<IList<PendingChange>> _getIncludedChanges;
        private readonly Func<IList<PendingChange>> _getExcludedChanges;

        public IList<PendingChange> IncludedChanges
        {
            get
            {
                return _getIncludedChanges();
            }
        }

        public IList<PendingChange> ExcludedChanges
        {
            get
            {
                return _getExcludedChanges();
            }
        }

        public PendingChangesInclusion(ITeamExplorer teamExplorer)
        {
            var pendingChangesPage = (TeamExplorerPageBase)teamExplorer.NavigateToPage(new Guid(TeamExplorerPageIds.PendingChanges), null);

            var model = pendingChangesPage.Model;
            var p = model.GetType().GetProperty("DataProvider", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

            var dataProvider = p.GetValue(model); // IPendingChangesDataProvider is internal;
            var dataProviderType = dataProvider.GetType();

            p = dataProviderType.GetProperty("IncludedChanges", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
            var m = p.GetMethod;
            _getIncludedChanges = (Func<IList<PendingChange>>)m.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IList<PendingChange>>), dataProvider);

            p = dataProviderType.GetProperty("ExcludedChanges", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
            m = p.GetMethod;
            _getExcludedChanges = (Func<IList<PendingChange>>)m.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IList<PendingChange>>), dataProvider);

            m = dataProviderType.GetMethod("IncludeChanges", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
            _includeChanges = (Action<IList<PendingChange>>)m.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<IList<PendingChange>>), dataProvider);

            m = dataProviderType.GetMethod("ExcludeChanges", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
            _excludeChanges = (Action<IList<PendingChange>>)m.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<IList<PendingChange>>), dataProvider);
        }

        public void IncludeChanges(IList<PendingChange> changes)
        {
            _includeChanges(changes);
        }

        public void ExcludeChanges(IList<PendingChange> changes)
        {
            _excludeChanges(changes);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to call the code above from within a VS Package object, you can use the following code:

```csharp
var teamExplorer = (ITeamExplorer)GetService(typeof(ITeamExplorer));
var psi = new PendingChangesInclusion(teamExplorer);

// To see if this works, include all excluded pending changes.
psi.IncludeChanges(psi.ExcludedChanges);
```

You will need to include the following assemblies using the "browse" dialog:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.5\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll

Comment: You're using GetService here, is that from TeamFoundationServer.GetService?

Comment: @Feign, in this case, I use [GetService() from the package itself] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package(v=vs.100).aspx). I'm not too sure, but I guess you can try other implementations of IServiceProvider as well.