# Don't checkin excluded file in TFS programmatically

Tags: c#

I'm trying programmatically to checkin files.

```
workspace.CheckIn(workspace.GetPendingChanges(), comment, null, workItemCheckinInfo, policyOverrideInfo);
```

In PendingChanges-Window of Visual Studio 2013 I can exclude files from checkin. If I run my program, everything is checkedin. Also the excluded files. Why? Is there possibility to avoid this? I tried to cloak the excluded file, I tried to remove the file from PendingChanges, but there is no possibility to set the new pending changes to workspace.
Any Ideas?
Arazon

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the PendingChanges, if you do not specify this parameter, all changes in the workspace are checked in. Also, if the set of pending changes for the check-in is null, the server tries to check in all changes in the workspace.
You can get some examples from [Extending Version Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130331(v=vs.120).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to first find out these included pending changes, and then only check in these included changes. Please check Munir Husseini's reply in this link for detailed information on how to get included changes: [how do I determine what items are included pending check-ins programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168976/how-do-i-determine-what-items-are-included-pending-check-ins-programatically)